# generic type restriction in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, generics

In C#, you can restrict a generic type:

```
public class Test<T> where T : SomeBaseClass
```

Can you do exactly the same thing in Visual Basic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.  You do this as:

```
Public Class Test(Of T As SomeBaseClass)
```

For details, see [Constraints in the Generic Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79.aspx) documentation.

Comment: I stripped the Visual Studio version from the URL. It will now fetch the most recent version (currently Visual Studio 2012)