# How to specify acceptable types in a Class (Of T)?

Tags: vb.net, types

I've declared a class called `WorkerPool(Of T)`. Right now it accepts every type (String, Boolean, Integer, etc.), except I would like it to only accept children types of `Worker`, like `FileWorker` or `MeshWorker`. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11973347/211627

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Public Class WorkerPool(Of T As Worker)

End Class
```

Comment: See [Generic Types in Visual Basic (Constraints)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79(v=vs.110).aspx#sectionToggle3)