# How can I update this function by adding a parameter to search for the exact control type, instead of only textboxes?

Tags: vb.net, lambda

I am building some libraries for my program's user inputs. How can I enhance my procedure by adding a parameter to clear `ErrorProvider` messages for the exact control type instead of only textboxes?

```vb
Friend Sub ClearErpMessages(Container As Control, ErpProvider As ErrorProvider)
    For Each tBox As TextBox In Container.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox).Where(Function(fTBox As TextBox) fTBox.Tag IsNot Nothing)
        ErpProvider.SetError(tBox, "")
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the procedure generic, and you need to apply a [generic constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11973347/11683) because the type `T` has to be a `Control`:

```vb
Friend Sub ClearErpMessages(Of T As Control)(ByVal Container As Control, ByVal ErpProvider As ErrorProvider)
    For Each ctl As T In Container.Controls.OfType(Of T).Where(Function(c As T) c.Tag IsNot Nothing)
        ErpProvider.SetError(ctl, "")
    Next
End Sub
```

```vb
ClearErpMessages(Of TextBox)(Me, error_provider)
ClearErpMessages(Of ComboBox)(Me, error_provider)
```

Comment: It was very usefull. Thanks for your help.